# Will this memory be freed properly?

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

I have a pair pointer let us suppose std::pair< A*, B* >* pointerpair. I allocated it memory and after using the pair i call delete pointerpair.

Will it also call delete A and delete B and will be freeing the memory completely ?

if i only call delete A and delete B but no delete pointerpair then is it a memory leak ?

Answer (score 3):

No.

However, in STL and Boost, there is a family of classes called smart pointers, which can automatically delete the objects whose pointers are stored in them. However, outside those smart pointer classes, any raw pointers stored in STL / Boost containers are simply treated as pointers. For example, you can define a set of raw pointers to strings. This set will be sorted using the pointer values, not the lexicographical order of the strings (unless you supply your comparison functor).

Answer (score 2):

No. It won't do it automatically. You have to delete it explicitly.